# How to export map routes into gpx file in google maps api android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, gpx

I am working on google maps api and I want to export the complete route (not only starting & ending coordinates) that is created by user into gpx file and then send the file to server. Can anyone please help me in exporting the route?

Comment: While working with google map apis for android, you could get polypoints (which will define your full route) instead of gpx file

Comment: In which form do you have all the points of the route now?

Comment: Basically I need to have the functionality in which user creates a route on google maps and then upload this route to the server (upload the complete route in gpx format)